# Is it possible to pass unprocessed parameters in a CALL command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Take for instance the following example files `a.bat` and `b.bat`:

**a.bat**

```
@echo off
echo in a: %*
call b %*
```

**b.bat**

```
@echo off
echo in b: %*
```

and consider this invocation and output:

```
c:\>a 1 2 3 %% %%%%
in a: 1 2 3 %% %%%%
in b: 1 2 3 % %%
```

Is there a way to pass the parameters from the command line to `b.bat` such that it sees the same parameters that `a.bat` saw? Is it possible to prevent the system from processing the parameters, i.e. removing the escaping `%` character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this looks so simple, I assume that I must have missed something, but from what you've posted, this looks like all you should need:

**C:\a.cmd**

```bash
@Echo In %~n0: %*
@Call "b.cmd" %%*
```

**C:\b.cmd**

```bash
@Echo In %~n0: %*
```

**Example:**

```bash
C:\>a 1 2 3 %% %%%%
In a: 1 2 3 %% %%%%
In b: 1 2 3 %% %%%%
```

Comment: Very nice! Though I believe characters `|`, `&`, `<` and `>` in the argument string could cause issues, and `^` is always problematic with `call`…

Comment: As you very probably know @aschipfl, my answer solves the specific scenario posted in the question area, at that time. If the OP wanted something else, then they should have expanded those examples. jeb however had already decided to read the hidden context, so there didn't seem to be a need for me to do so. The OP and future readers should also be aware that the common way to pass arguments to a script through `cmd.exe` would be to doublequote those arguments, and/or escape where necessary poison characters, so real world examples should have been submitted, instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that, but instead of removing a character, you need to add more escape characters.
But to solve it for any (or at least most) parameter you need to escape all problematic characters `&|<>"^`
This can handle even parameters like:
`a.bat Bob^&Alice say: "Cat & dog"`

```
@echo off
REM *** Fetch all arguments
goto :init :initCallBack
:initCallBack

REM *** Prepare the arguments for a secure CALL
call :prepareArgument allArgs arg

REM *** b.bat will see the same arguments like this file
call b.bat %%allArgs%%
exit /b

:init
::: Get all arguments with minimal interference
::: Only linefeeds and carriage returns can't be fetched
::: Only linefeeds can create a syntax error
::: return arg=All arguments, arg1..arg<n>=A single argument
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "argCnt="
:getArgs
>"%temp%\getArg.txt" <"%temp%\getArg.txt" (
  setlocal DisableExtensions
  (set prompt=#)
  echo on
  if defined argCnt (
    for %%a in (%%a) do rem . %1.
  ) ELSE (
    for %%a in (%%a) do rem . %*.
  )
  echo off
  endlocal

  set /p "arg%argCnt%="
  set /p "arg%argCnt%="
  set "arg%argCnt%=!arg%argCnt%:~7,-2!"
  if defined arg%argCnt% (
    if defined argCnt (
        shift /1
    )
    set /a argCnt+=1
    goto :getArgs
  ) else set /a argCnt-=1
)
del "%temp%\getArg.txt"
goto :initCallBack

:prepareArgument
::: Convert a string, so it can be used as an argument for calling a program
set "var=!%~2!"
if defined var (
    set "var=!var:^=^^!"
    set "var=!var:"=^^"!"
    set "var=!var:&=^&!"
    set "var=!var:|=^|!"
    set "var=!var:>=^>!"
    set "var=!var:<=^<!"
)
set "%~1=!var!"
exit /b
```